# Material component is not a known element - angular2

Tags: angular

I have installed @angular/material and have imported {MaterialModule} from '@angular/material'.

But still I am not able to use any md-tags as it shows up "Not a known element" error. Please advice on this.

Comment: Please provide some more information. How is your configuration defined? Are you using systemjs or webpack?

Comment: installed using angular-cli, package.json file has the dependency, @angular/material

Comment: Have you included the import in `app.module.ts`?

Comment: yes in app.module only

Comment: I've provided an answer that should help, although I couldn't find a valid element md-tags

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that you reference the components you want from material in your `app.component.ts` e.g.

```
import { MdDialog, MdDialogRef, MdSnackBar } from '@angular/material';
```